# React navigation swipe gesture winning over horizontal scrollview

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have a horizontal scrollview which is part of a [tab component](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-scrollable-tab-view), and it works, but when swiping right, it makes the gesture to swipe back and ignores the scrollview.

I know I can disable it in the whole screen but I just want to disable it for this scrollview. Is there any way to do this?

The screen has this config:

```
{
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    gesturesEnabled: true,
    gestureResponseDistance: { horizontal: 1000 }
  },
  mode: 'card',
  transitionConfig: () => StackViewTransitionConfigs.SlideFromRightIOS
}
```